# How to navigate outside of react component using react router 6

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Right now I have an History module, that let me use the history even outside of react component:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then I use this history in App.jsx directly

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Router history={history}>...</Router>
```

I can import and use the same history object everywhere. Even in custom helpers outside of any react components.

How could this work in **react router 6**?

Since history is replaced with navigate, I don't see any solution yet online.

I know it is still beta, but I would like to check on it in advance.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: hey, I have the same problem. did you find any solution?

Comment: @pedramafra Yes, I just wrote the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up with following solutions:

At first, react-router-dom 6 has navigate and not history. It is better to use navigate for the navigation trough the routes:

I create and fix my History object, so that it can continue work with 'push' and that I don't need big rework:

```
const History = {
  navigate: null,
  push: (page, ...rest) => History.navigate(page, ...rest),
};

export default History;
```

Then I made my own Component that set the navigation:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavigateSetter = () => {
  History.navigate = useNavigate();

  return null;
};
```

Then while defining the default router, I place as a child the setter:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
    <NavigateSetter />
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

After that you can use everywhere History.push or History.navigate with the default react-router-dom's navigate API.

Comment: this is a great workaround. thanks

Comment: a good way to reach this

Comment: great, all i had to do was move browserrouter higher up!  thanks

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by @bukso, I ended up with the following solution in *TypeScript*.

**global-history.tsx**

```
import { useNavigate, NavigateFunction } from "react-router-dom";

export let globalNavigate: NavigateFunction;

export const GlobalHistory = () => {
  globalNavigate = useNavigate();

  return null;
};
```

**index.tsx**

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <GlobalHistory />
    {/* ... */}
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Now, you're ready to use it outside React components. `globalNavigate("profile")`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed access to the history object before first render, so I ended up writing custom component around `Router` based on the `BrowserRouter` implementation that would allow me to pass in history through props.

See https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8241#discussioncomment-1677474 for code.

**Edit:**
As of react-router-dom v6.1.0 HistoryRouter is part of its implementation so you can just directly do:

```js
import {unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<HistoryRouter history={history} />
```

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is good solution. The react-router team explicitly move from history to navigate with the goal of "better compatibility with React suspense"


https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Comment: @bukso As I wrote in the edit, they added it themselves to the library in 6.1

Comment: Kadlek, okay, but it is still unstable - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I wanted to navigate from the navbar back to the home page.

Create a `HistoryRouter` component & wrap your navbar or similar & then create react browser router separately for your routes.

```
import {createBrowserRouter, Link, unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter} from "react-router-dom";


export const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });

const App = () => {
    return (
       <>
          <HistoryRouter history={history}>
             <Navbar />
           </HistoryRouter>
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
       </>
    );
}
```

Then create a function that uses the history object to push the new path in the window's location.

```
import {history} from "../app";


export const logout = (to: string): void => {
    // e.g removeToken();
    history.push(to);
    window.location.reload();
};
```

I can now use the `logout` function in my navbar, for example:

```
<nav>
    <button onClick={_ => logout("/")}>Logout</button>
</nav>
```